# JSON Deserialization in .NET service - can't solve this issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, vb.net, deserialization

I've spent a couple days on this issue to no avail. I simply need to deserialize a JSON object in VB.NET but am constantly getting this error:

"Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array."

I have used every suggestion I have found to try and fix this but none have worked.

Here is my JQuery code:

```
          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Services/Data_Services.asmx/AssignRoles",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ roleAssignments: roleassignments }),
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Group assignments successfully set");
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
```

This outputs:
{"roleAssignments":[{"groupid":"2","role":"4","staffid":"111"},{"groupid":"2","role":"5","staffid":"999"},{"groupid":"2","role":"6","staffid":"999"},{"groupid":"2","role":"7","staffid":"0"},{"groupid":"2","role":"8","staffid":"999"},{"groupid":"2","role":"9","staffid":"15"}]}

(JSON is valid. I have checked it in JSONLint)

Here is the .NET code which returns the error in the deserialization function:

```
Public Function AssignRoles(ByVal roleAssignments As String) As String()
[.........] 

Dim aRoleList As New List(Of roleAssignments)
Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
aRoleList = js.Deserialize(Of List(Of roleAssignments))(roleAssignments)

[.........]
End Function

Public Class roleAssignments
   Public Property groupid As String
   Public Property role As String
   Public Property staffid As String
End Class
```

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this? I'm completely stumped and from reading other examples, I seem to be following the correct syntax but can not understand what the issue is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this on my own. Turns out the List object wasn't the issue. It was the way I was passing the JSON into the web service. I had to escape the quotes and changed the JSON.stringify syntax. JSON.stringify passed into another JSON.stringify adds an escape to the quotes.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Services/Data_Services.asmx/AssignRoles",
                data: "{ \"roleJSON\": " + JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(roleassignments)) + "}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                        // parse return data here....
                        showSuccessMessage("Group assignments set");
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("Error occurred:" + response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert("Insert failed: " + response.responseText);
                }
            });
```

I left the VB code alone, except for removing the new keyword from the List declaration and changing the name of the JSON string being passed in.

```
 Dim aRoleList As List(Of roleAssignments)
 Dim returnedValue As New List(Of String)
 Try
     Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
     aRoleList = js.Deserialize(Of List(Of roleAssignments))(roleJSON)
[.....]
```

I wanted to post the solution so anyone else who might be having the same issue can figure it out. As usual with development, the syntax is usually the culprit.

Comment: JSON request will look like this when sent: { "roleJSON": "[{\"groupid\":\"1\",\"role\":\"4\",\"staffid\":\"515\"},{\"groupid\":\"1\",\"role\":\"5\",\"staffid\":\"489\"},{\"groupid\":\"1\",\"role\":\"6\",\"staffid\":\"464\"},{\"groupid\":\"1\",\"role\":\"7\",\"staffid\":\"126\"},{\"groupid\":\"1\",\"role\":\"8\",\"staffid\":\"306\"},{\"groupid\":\"1\",\"role\":\"9\",\"staffid\":\"15\"}]"}

Comment: I am glad you solved your problem, but this does not actually answer the original question.  Someone else reading it in one of the Review Queues might well DV it. The answer I posted works fine ([see this Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TiQ23z)).  Also, your new JSON fails JSONLint.

Comment: Agreed that the JSON shown here does not pass in JSONLint but apparently the VB object I am passing the code into needs the quotes escaped to properly understand the string and deserialize it.